# Power Query парсить информацию со всплывающей страницы сайта

Tags: парсер, excel, запрос

Есть сайт фондовой биржи. На сайте в углу есть кнопка "ТОРГОВАЯ ИНФОРМАЦИЯ", при нажатии на которую вызывается страница с информацией по торгам на бирже. Как можно с помощью Power Query правильно спарсить данную страницу? Ссылка [здесь](https://kase.kz/ru/#trade_info_period). У меня при обычном Get From Web по этой ссылке парситься только главная страница, а всплывающая нет. Как быть?

Дополнение: Во всплывающем окне необходимо зайти во вкладку *Результаты торгов за день* и парсить таблицы по акциям и т.д.

Скрин: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В PowerQuery можно написать запрос:

```
    (date)=>
    let
        Источник = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://kase.kz/ru/trade_information/period-archive-xls/" & date & "/" & date & "/"), null, true),
        #"Торговая информация 01.12.2022_Sheet" = Источник{[Item="Торговая информация " & date,Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
    in
        #"Торговая информация 01.12.2022_Sheet"
```

и в качестве параметров задавать дату с апострофом вначале ('01.12.2022)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получим результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Igor  спасибо вам за интересное решение. Но мне нужно немного другое. Я дополнил вопрос и приложил скрин...